# Question about the definition of a simplicial map

Tags: algebraic-topology

By the definition of my textbook, let $K$ and $L$ be two complexes, a function $s: |K|\rightarrow |L|$ is a **simplicial map** if it takes simplexes of $K$ linearly onto simplexes of $L$, i.e.

$(1)$ whenever $A$ is a simplex of $K$ then $s(A)$ is a simplex of $L$ and
$(2)$ if $A$ has vertices $v_0,\cdots, v_k$ and $x\in A = \lambda_0v_0 + \cdots + \lambda_kv_k$, then $s(x) = \lambda_0s(v_0) + \cdots + \lambda_ks(v_k)$.

My question is, if a simplex $A$ of $K$ has vertices $v_0,\cdots, v_k$, are $s(v_0), \cdots, s(v_k)$ vertices of $s(A)$?

I know this should be obvious but from the definition of a simplicial map, I can only infer that $(1)$ $s(v_0), \cdots, s(v_k)$ are some vertices of $L$ and $(2)$ the set $\{s(v_0), \cdots, s(v_k)\}$ contain all the vertices of $s(A)$. Can some of $\{s(v_0), \cdots, s(v_k)\}$ be non-vertices of $s(A)$, let's say, an interior of $s(A)$?

For example, can I have a *simplicial* map between the complexes below which maps the colored vertex to the corresponding colored vertex?

[image]

Sorry I just realized that the complex $L$ should comprise of the two line segments, the longer line, and all the vertices.

Comment: Which textbook do you use?

Comment: Basic Topology by Armstrong @PaulFrost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot happen.

As you know, each $\{s(v_i)\}$ is a $0$-simplex in $L$. Since $B = s(A)$ is a simplex in $L$, the intersection $\{s(v_i)\} \cap B = \{s(v_i)\}$ is face of $B$. This is possible only when $s(v_i)$ is a vertex of $B$.

Comment: Thank you! @Paul Frost